# rvest html_table

Tags: r, html-table, rvest

I am trying to extract a table using `html_table` and the `rvest` package

```
library(rvest)
test <- html("http://www.privacyrights.org/data-breach/new?title=")
test %>% html_table(html_nodes("table.data-breach-table")[[1]])
```

however, I keep getting an error

> Error in UseMethod("html_nodes"):    no applicable method for
>   'html_nodes' applied to an object of class "character"

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to nest parenthesized calls anyway, why bother with piping?

```
html_table(html_nodes(test, "table.data-breach-table")[[1]])
```

Otherwise go full pipe and use `magrittr` as well:

```
library(magrittr)

test %>% 
  html_nodes("table.data-breach-table") %>% 
  extract2(1) %>%
  html_table()
```

NOTE:

- the URL you are using does not have the table you want anyway
- you should be using the newest `rvest` and using `read_html`

As far as why it wasn't working, you were piping `test` incorrectly and `html_nodes` was operating on the `table…` string instead of the parsed HTML document it expects.

Since you're trying to scrape breaches, this may be of help:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(pbapply)

urls <- sprintf("http://www.privacyrights.org/data-breach?title=&page=%d", 1:94)

pblapply(urls, function(URL) {

  pg <- read_html(URL)

  tab <- html_nodes(pg, "table")[3]
  rows <- html_nodes(tab, "tr:not(.data-breach-bottom)")

  bind_rows(lapply(seq(2, length(rows)-2, by=2), function(i) {

    tds_1 <- html_nodes(rows[i], "td")
    tds_2 <- html_text(html_nodes(rows[i+1], "td"), trim=TRUE)

    data_frame(date_public=html_text(tds_1[1], TRUE),
               name_loc=html_text(tds_1[2], TRUE),
               entity=html_text(tds_1[3], TRUE),
               type=html_text(tds_1[4], TRUE),
               recs=html_text(tds_1[5], TRUE),
               descr=tds_2[1])

  }))

}) -> things
```

It's from an older [gitst](https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/dd9d731748b22f11def2) of mine. You'll need to add a randomized sleep delay to that if you do plan on scraping all their breaches.

NOTE also that it's skewed data and be very aware of it's limitations as you attempt to use it (I do data breach research for a living).

Comment: Thank you so much, I would be interested in any other data breach sources you could recommend

Comment: I'd actually recommend joining the [Society of Information Risk Analysts](http://lists.societyinforisk.org/mailman/listinfo/sira) (it's free) and poking around the archives (lots of links). There's also <vcdb.org>. Much depends on what you're trying to accomplish, though.

Comment: Hi, I ran the code quickly just to try and understand how it works. I am very new to R so struggling with the software a little bit - it gave me an error Error: expecting an external pointer
Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)

Comment: There's also a [not-so-secret URL](https://www.privacyrights.org/sites/privacyrights.org/files/static/Chronology-of-Data-Breaches_-_Privacy-Rights-Clearinghouse.csv) that provides a CSV of the all but the most really recent breaches (it's an ugly CSV tho)

Comment: the scraping broke due to a format change on their end. the code block works now.